# How to check if the folders are the same using variables in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, scripting, directory

given the bash code below, i am defining a variable to represent a folder and i am checking if it is a folder. I can even browse into it using the variable name.

There is a small catch here, i defined the folder's name with '/' as the last character, because the tab completion completes the string this way.

```
#! /bin/bash


VAR_LOG='/var/log/'


echo $VAR_LOG
echo $PWD

echo "browsing to log directory"
cd $VAR_LOG
echo $PWD


if [ -d $VAR_LOG ]; then
    echo "$VAR_LOG is a directory"
fi

if [ ${VAR_LOG} != ${PWD} ]
then echo not same
else 
echo same
fi
```

But as you can see, $PWD defines the same path/folder without '/' as the last character and the string comparison will result as false. Even though i am in the same folder and the cd $LOG_DIR will take me to the same folder.

```
User1-MBP:log User1$ $HOME/tmp.sh 
/var/log/
/Users/User1
browsing to log directory
/var/log
/var/log/ is a directory
not same
```

So, what is the best way to work with directories in bash? Keeping them as strings is somewhat error-prone.

(NOTE: this is a MacOS system - i am not sure if it should make any difference)

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about string equality, you can strip the trailing `\` from `VAR_LOG` by using `${VAR_LOG%/}` expansion (*Remove matching suffix pattern*). This will strip one (last `/` from `VAR_LOG` if present and leave it unchanged when not:

```
if [ "${VAR_LOG%/}" != "${PWD}" ]; ...
```

However, you can also (and probably should) use `-ef` test:

> `FILE1 -ef FILE2
>       FILE1 and FILE2 have the same device and inode numbers`

I.e.:

```
if [ ! "${VAR_LOG}" -ef "${PWD}" ]; ...
```

Ensure both file/directory names refer to the same file.

This is not relevant for directories, but different filenames referring to the same inode (hardlinks) would evaluate to `0` on `-ef` test.